# Get from database to color polygon PHP

Tags: php, mysql, polygon

I have a database with the following structure.

```
Index    Output

  1       1
  2       2
  3       1
  4       1
  5       3
  6       1
  7       2
  8       1
  9       3
 10       2
 11       2
 12       3
```

I am looking to create a 3X4 matrix of squares (kinda like a tic tac toe game and paint them according to the output). So if the output is 1 I'll paint that square red, if the output is 2, I'll paint that square blue and if the output is 3 I'll paint that square green. The squares kinda look like this (except I'm using graphics)

```
 -- -- --
|  |  |  |
 -- -- --
|  |  |  |
 -- -- --
|  |  |  |
 -- -- -- 
|  |  |  |
 -- -- --
```

I understand that I can use polygon function to draw and fill shapes but do I write 12 arrays defining 12 different sets of four coordinates or is there a simpler way

I am doing the following right now

```
<?php

$user_name = "root";
$password = "pass";
$database = "db";
$server = "127.0.0.1";

$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

$blue = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 255);
$red = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 0, 0);
$green = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 255, 0);
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 300);
$col_poly = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

if ($db_found) {
for ($i = 0 ; $i<=12 ; $i=$i+1) {

    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM table1 where index like " . $i
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
    while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if  ($db_field['Result'] == 1) { // and similarly for blue and green 

            imagepolygon($image, array(
                 0,   0,
                     0,  10,
                 10, 10,
                 10, 0
            ),
            4,
        $col_poly);

imagefilledpolygon($image, $values, 6, $red
}
 // and so on for others 
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: It looks like your getting each color from the db individually. Wouldn't it make more sense to collect all 12 at once? Also, `imagefilledpolygon($image, $values, 6, $red` is missing a closing `)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of maths should help! If we calculate what column and row a given number should appear in then the rest should be fairly simple. These two lines should help:

```
$col = ($i-1)%3;
$row = floor(($i-1)/3);
```

And to put them in context, I think something like the below should work:

```
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    switch($db_field['Result']) {
        case 1: $colour = $blue; break;
        case 2: $colour = $red; break;
        case 3: $colour = $green; break;
    }
    $i = $db_field['index'];
    $col = ($i-1)%3;
    $row = floor(($i-1)/3);
    imagefilledpolygon($image, array(
        $row*10, $col*10,
        $row*10, $col*10+10,
        $row*10+10, $col*10+10,
        $row*10+10, $col*10
    ),4,$colour);
}
```

Comment: $col = ($i-1)%3 should be some other variable name as $col is color